# Why doesn't my code work without this alert box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

On one of the edit views of my Grails application I have several chained drop down boxes.  When the edit view is called all the values for the object being edited populate correctly, but none of the drop down boxes are populated because they populate via AJAX through jQuery's `change` function.

To fix this I used the code below, but there is one strange thing.  I used an alert box to see what the value was when I was writing the code.  With the alert box there everything happens as I expect it to, but as soon as I remove the alert box the line of code that re-selects the previously cleared value stops working.

```
<g:javascript>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    cargoDestinationValue = $("#cargoDestination\\.id").val(); //Gets value shown in the selection box. This box is second in the chain.
    $("#account\\.id ").trigger('change'); //Triggers a change.  This box is first in the chain. when a change is detected an AJAX call is made via some other JavaScript and that populates the second selection box in the chain, but doing so clears the selected value.
    alert(cargoDestinationValue); //If this is not here the next line does not seem to be doing what it is supposed to do.
    $("#cargoDestination\\.id").val(cargoDestinationValue); //This re-selects the value that was previously cleared.
  })
</g:javascript>
```

What is the deal here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event that you trigger is queued, so if you don't have the alert, the event is not handled until you exit the function.

Even if you would call the code directly without using an event to trigger it, it has an AJAX call where the response is handled by an event, so that event would be queued.

You should handle the part after the alert in the code that recieves the data from the AJAX call, which of course means that you have to store the selected value somewhere so that the code can get to it.

Comment: I think one of us is misunderstanding the other. I know that the event that the change event I triggered completed correctly, because the second box in the chain has all the values it should have. The only problem is that the proper value is not selected in the second box in the chain, instead it just says " -Select-". The first line of my code stores the proper selected value, and the last line sets it.

Comment: @typoknig: The problem is that the options in the select box doesn't get there until after you exit the function. When you try to select one of them on the last line, they aren't there yet. All that exists at that point is a change event that is waiting to be handled, which will then start the download of the values.

Comment: I see, what you are saying now. I adjusted the function with the AJAX call to first read the value of the selection box, then, re-select that value upon success of the AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that #cargoDestination does not exist at the moment you try to set the value (without the alert box), but will be loaded/inserted while you click "ok" if the alert box is on screen?

I had a similar problem some days ago...